# Mysql query - Operand should contain 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I went through several topics here talking about this but I could not get it to work. For each "pot" I want to get the number of payments as well as the full commission (sum of all payment commissions) related to this pot.

```
SELECT id, id_user,
       ( SELECT IFNULL( SUM(amount), 0 ) AS collectedA, 
                IFNULL( SUM(commission), 0 ) AS commission 
                FROM payment AS pay WHERE pay.id_pot = pot.id AND pay.stat = 1 ) FROM pot
```

Above gives me the error mentioned in the title. I understand we can't select two columns with this kind of subquery.
I tried to go through LEFT OUTER JOIN but could not get it to work.

```
SELECT id, id_user, 
       IFNULL( SUM(payment.amount), 0 ) AS collectedA, 
       IFNULL( SUM(payment.commission), 0 ) AS commission
FROM pot LEFT OUTER JOIN payment ON payment.id_pot = pot.id AND payment.stat = 1
```

But this gives me strange results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LEFT JOIN` is correct, but you forgot to use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT pot.id, id_user, 
       IFNULL( SUM(payment.amount), 0 ) AS collectedA, 
       IFNULL( SUM(payment.commission), 0 ) AS commission
FROM pot 
LEFT OUTER JOIN payment ON payment.id_pot = pot.id AND payment.stat = 1
GROUP BY pot.id
```

If you need a `WHERE` clause to select only some of the pots, put it after `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT pot.id, id_user, 
       IFNULL( SUM(payment.amount), 0 ) AS collectedA, 
       IFNULL( SUM(payment.commission), 0 ) AS commission
FROM pot 
LEFT OUTER JOIN payment ON payment.id_pot = pot.id AND payment.stat = 1
WHERE ...
GROUP BY pot.id
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. How better is that compared to Giorgos' solution? I have to say I am a bit concerned with calculating too much for only a small part of the list.

Comment: When you have a `WHERE` clause, this should avoid calculating the sums for unrelated payments.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `LEFT JOIN` to an *already aggregated* derived table, like this:

```
SELECT id, id_user, collectedA, commission 
FROM pot 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT id_pot,
          IFNULL( SUM(amount), 0 ) AS collectedA, 
          IFNULL( SUM(commission), 0 ) AS commission 
   FROM payment  
   WHERE stat = 1 
   GROUP BY id_pot
) AS pay pay.id_pot = pot.id
```

The `GROUP BY` performed in the subquery guarantees that you will get *exactly one record* per `pot.id`.

Comment: Thanks Giorgos. This would select all the pots. If I had a where clause to select only part of them, where would I put it to make it efficient? On both subqueries? I would like to prevent it to calculate the sum for every single pots if I only need just a few ... Any help appreciated.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient method may be two subqueries, especially if you want to have filters on the `pot` table:

```
select pot.id, pot.id_user,
       (select sum(pay.amount)
        from payment pay
        where pay.id_pot = pot.id and pay.stat = 1
       ) as amount,
       (select sum(pay.commission)
        from payment pay
        where pay.id_pot = pot.id and pay.stat = 1
       ) as commission
from pot;
```

For this to work efficiently, you need an index on `payment(id_pot, stat, amount, commission)`.  This is a covering index for both queries (meaning that all the columns are in the index.

It may seem counterintuitive that this is faster, but it requires no global aggregation -- all the aggregation can be handled using index scans.  That is often faster.  In addition, any additional filters on `pot` reduce the work need on the `payment` table.